# Issues with PhotoUrl

Tags: image, tumblr

I'm trying to edit a tumblr layout so to be able to see an image at full height/width just scaled down. As far as I understand it can be done with max-width/max-height being set to 100% while still staying inside it's original container.

My problem is that every time I try to change the settings under PhotoUrl to something other than the pre-prescribed -500, -250, etc. the entire image just goes blank.

This is the coding:

```
{block:Photo}
<center>{block:IndexPage}{LinkOpenTag}<a href="{permalink}">
<table width="500" height="200" "border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tr>
<td background="{PhotoURL-500}" style="background-position:center center;">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
</table>
</a>{LinkCloseTag}
{/block:IndexPage}
```

Thank you to anyone who can help!

Answer (score 0):

This is what you should use for the high res image:

```
{PhotoURL-HighRes}
```

Also, you're going to run into problems with your `{LinkOpenTag}` and `{Permalink}` link. You should remove one or the other. `{LinkOpenTag}` will actually render an anchor tag, so in your case you'll end up with this:

```
<a href="/link/here"><a href="/link/here"><!-- photo stuff --></a></a>
```